Do I have a problem? Wood-eating pests vs. something else?
Photos
The last couple of days I've been finding this particular insect type (see image) on my laminate floor in the hallway. I did use Home Defense from Home Depot a few weeks ago as a preventative measure, which might explain why they're dead? However, if these are termites or wood-boring insects, I'm not sure the product I used would be effective against them?
For context, I live in a newly built house (about 2 years old) in Portland, Oregon. This is the first time I've encountered this type of bug, thus my curiosity and concern. After briefly researching and looking at some online pictures, I thought it might be a carpenter ant, or possibly some kind of wood-eating termite. Since it is a new build perhaps a pinhole bore?
I'm concerned about the possibility of wood-damaging pests in my new home. Can you help me identify what these insects might be and advise on any necessary steps I should take?
